# jquery: wrap n siblings and position them behind n elements

Tags: jquery, position, wrapall

I'm destroying myself to get to a solution working in JQuery for the following prob: Inside a container I have a bunch of items and modals.

Depending on the screen solution I want to wrap the modals inside a row and position that row right after the last related item.

This is what the starting list looks like:

```
<div class="overview">
    <div class="item n0">Item</div>
    <div class="item n1">Item</div>
    <div class="item n2">Item</div>
    <div class="item n3">Item</div>
    <div class="item n4">Item</div>
    <div class="item n5">Item</div>
    <div class="item n6">Item</div>
    <div class="item n7">Item</div>
    <div class="item n8">Item</div>
    <div class="item n9">Item</div>
    <div class="modal n0">Modal</div>
    <div class="modal n1">Modal</div>
    <div class="modal n2">Modal</div>
    <div class="modal n3">Modal</div>
    <div class="modal n4">Modal</div>
    <div class="modal n5">Modal</div>
    <div class="modal n6">Modal</div>
    <div class="modal n7">Modal</div>
    <div class="modal n8">Modal</div>
    <div class="modal n9">Modal</div>
</div>
```

To display the row containing the 3 connected modals after the 3 items the outcome should look like this:

```
<div class="overview">
    <div class="item n0">Item</div>
    <div class="item n1">Item</div>
    <div class="item n2">Item</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="modal n0">Modal</div>
            <div class="modal n1">Modal</div>
            <div class="modal n2">Modal</div>
        </div>
    <div class="item n3">Item</div>
    <div class="item n4">Item</div>
    <div class="item n5">Item</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="modal n3">Modal</div>
            <div class="modal n4">Modal</div>
            <div class="modal n5">Modal</div>
        </div>
    <div class="item n6">Item</div>
    <div class="item n7">Item</div>
    <div class="item n8">Item</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="modal n6">Modal</div>
            <div class="modal n7">Modal</div>
            <div class="modal n8">Modal</div>
        </div>
    <div class="item n9">Item</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="modal n9">Modal</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also tried to setup a fiddle here: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tojai/3p3415qo/16/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=3p3415qo) but for the heck of it I don't get it to work at all. Would any of you guys be able to help?

Thanks so much,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/3p3415qo/29/

```js
var modals = $('.overview > .modal');

for(var i = 0; i < modals.length; i+=3) {
  $('.overview > div[class="item n' + (i+2) + '"]').after("<div class='row row" + i + "'></div>")
  $('.row' + i).html($('div[class="modal n' + i +'"], div[class="modal n' + (i+1) +'"], div[class="modal n' + (i+2) +'"]').clone());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overview">
  <div class="item n0">Item</div>
  <div class="item n1">Item</div>
  <div class="item n2">Item</div>
  <div class="item n3">Item</div>
  <div class="item n4">Item</div>
  <div class="item n5">Item</div>
  <div class="item n6">Item</div>
  <div class="item n7">Item</div>
  <div class="item n8">Item</div>
  <div class="item n9">Item</div>
  <div class="modal n0">Modal</div>
  <div class="modal n1">Modal</div>
  <div class="modal n2">Modal</div>
  <div class="modal n3">Modal</div>
  <div class="modal n4">Modal</div>
  <div class="modal n5">Modal</div>
  <div class="modal n6">Modal</div>
  <div class="modal n7">Modal</div>
  <div class="modal n8">Modal</div>
  <div class="modal n9">Modal</div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Great, this works pretty well for all case where I don't have to show only one. I'll try to get this working tho.

Comment: i did but this doesn't count as i'm a noob here :\